# Multi-user gaze with the Hololens 2 in the same collocated space Photon Engine PUN

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I am currently developing a mixed reality space using the Photon Engine in Unity and was wondering what would be the best method for accessing each individual user's Gaze information from the their Hololens 2.

At the moment, I have the associated Toolkit, SceneContent, and Playspace with the scene itself. However, when I access gaze data using CoreServices.InputSystem.EyeGazeProvider I only receive the information from the master client in my PUN (PhotonEngine) server (Which makes sense). I was thinking I would attach a (Toolkit, SceneContent, and Playspace) as child objects to the User prefab I have already created so each individual user can have their own toolkits. Any help or suggestions on the topic would greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `so each individual user can have their own toolkits.` ... if they all run the app on their own HoloLens .. wouldn't that e the case anyway? Every client should locally access their very own gaze points  - anything else would surprise me a lot ^^